# R FAMD Plotting multiple errors

Tags: r, plot, graph

my dataframe temp3 look like this:

```
> print(temp3)
# A tibble: 20 × 5
   APTname            Table_Types     Techniques_N_Software Tactic_s            Domain             
 * <chr>              <chr>           <chr>                 <chr>               <chr>              
 1 admin@338          Techniques Used T1087.001             Discovery           Enterprise         
 2 admin@338          Techniques Used T1049                 Discovery           Enterprise         
 3 admin@338          Techniques Used T1007                 Discovery           Enterprise         
 4 admin@338          Techniques Used T1204.002             Execution           Enterprise         
 5 admin@338          Software        S0043                 ThisIsAMissingValue ThisIsAMissingValue
 6 admin@338          Software        S0100                 ThisIsAMissingValue ThisIsAMissingValue
 7 admin@338          Software        S0042                 ThisIsAMissingValue ThisIsAMissingValue
 8 admin@338          Software        S0039                 ThisIsAMissingValue ThisIsAMissingValue
 9 admin@338          Software        S0104                 ThisIsAMissingValue ThisIsAMissingValue
10 admin@338          Software        S0012                 ThisIsAMissingValue ThisIsAMissingValue
11 admin@338          Software        S0096                 ThisIsAMissingValue ThisIsAMissingValue
12 admin@338          Techniques Used T1059.003             Execution           Enterprise         
13 admin@338          Techniques Used T1203                 Execution           Enterprise         
14 admin@338          Techniques Used T1083                 Discovery           Enterprise         
15 admin@338          Techniques Used T1036.005             Defense Evasion     Enterprise         
16 admin@338          Techniques Used T1069.001             Discovery           Enterprise         
17 admin@338          Techniques Used T1566.001             Initial Access      Enterprise         
18 admin@338          Techniques Used T1082                 Discovery           Enterprise         
19 admin@338          Techniques Used T1016                 Discovery           Enterprise         
20 Ajax Security Team Techniques Used T1566.003             Initial Access      Enterprise
```

1st error

when trying (https://statisticsglobe.com/pca-categorical-variables?unapproved=63523&moderation-hash=a394f15e378dd59d51b646b45f638293#comment-63523):

```
arthiris_famd <- FAMD(temp3,
                  ncp = 2, 
                  graph = TRUE)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in `geom_segment()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 3rd layer.
Caused by error:
! object 'df_var' not found
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning messages:
1: ggrepel: 18 unlabeled data points (too many overlaps). Consider increasing max.overlaps 
2: ggrepel: 24 unlabeled data points (too many overlaps). Consider increasing max.overlaps 
3: ggrepel: 18 unlabeled data points (too many overlaps). Consider increasing max.overlaps 
4: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (`geom_point()`). 
5: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (`geom_text_repel()`). 
6: ggrepel: 24 unlabeled data points (too many overlaps). Consider increasing max.overlaps
```

so i tried a second option http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/31-principal-component-methods-in-r-practical-guide/115-famd-factor-analysis-of-mixed-data-in-r-essentials/

2nd error

and in it when i try to do this:

```
fviz_famd_var(res.famd, "quanti.var", repel = TRUE,
          col.var = "black")
```

I get this error:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
```

arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1

Lastly a weird thing i noticed is that in my res.famd my quanti.var is empty and it is my assumtion that it should be full much like var.

see picture for comparison.

[image]

One proposition from google bard was to factor my temp3 data in my dataframe, but it yielded the same results and error as previously described.

I welcome your advise,
kind regards.